# c++ Returning reference to single row of matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

So I have a struct called Vector, using a template to allow it to have a varied length if needed.   It contains an array to store the elements of the Vector.

```
template <class T = float, int N = 3>
struct Vector
{
    T data[N];
```

and another called Matrix which is essentially a Vector with N*N elements in the data array.

```
template <class T = float, int N = 3>
struct Matrix : public Vector <T, N*N>
{
    Matrix() {}
```

In one of the functions for Matrix, I need to return one of its "rows" as a Vector so that any changes made to that Vector are also changed in the row of the Matrix.

```
inline Vector<T, N>& operator[](int row)
{
}
```

I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: You could return a pointer-to-`T` pointing to the first element in that row, but that may be a bit too "raw" for your tastes. You could instead have a `Matrix::Row` class that contains a reference to the `Matrix` object, and has an `operator[]` that indexes that far into the row.

Comment: @cdhowie I should also have mentioned that the return type needs to be Vector<T, N>&. It's for homework, but I can't seem to remember how to do this at all.

Comment: Is `struct Matrix : public Vector <T, N*N>` required or are you allowed to change this?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice It's required

Comment: Actually, I think I figured it out, it seems to compile with `return (Vector<T, N>&)data[N*row]` I knew it had to be some combination of casts, it just took me over an hour to get to that. Should I answer it and leave it up? Or is this too simple of a question to matter, and I should just delete it.

Comment: Ahh...your question didn't mention that you have a conversion constructor. Perhaps `return Vector<T, N>(&data[N*row])` would be more clear.

Comment: If you've answered it yourself then by all means post it as an answer. It's not only ok, It is encoraged.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you should change your `Matrix` class to be a "vector of vectors" rather than a single linear vector:

```
struct Matrix : public Vector <Vector<T, N> , N>
```

Now you get the desired behavior for free assuming a correct implementation of `operator[]` for `Vector`.

Comment: Bummer this isn't an option for the OP, because it seems a natural fit. You can do it with a `using` template alias in C++11, btw. [sample](http://pastebin.com/1egCDyjB).

Answer (score 1):

The data for the `i`-th row starts at `data[i*N]`.

```
template <class T = float, int N = 3>
struct Matrix : public Vector <T, N*N>
{
    Matrix() {}
    T* operator[](int i)
    {
       return &data[i*N];
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
Matrix<int, 10> m;
m[5][5] = 10;
```

Comment: `data[I*N]` would be a reference, `&data[I*N]` would be a pointer that points to the start of the `I`-th row of data.

Answer (score 1):

If what are looking for is just to be able to address individual elements then you might also consider overloading the function call operator instead.

```
template <class T = float, int N = 3>
struct Matrix : public Vector <T, N*N>
{
    Matrix() {}
    T& operator()(int row, int col)
    {
       return /*element*/;
    }
};
```

This way all element access is done through the `Matrix` class without the requirement for the intermediate `Vector`.

The usage then becomes:

```
Matrix< int, 10 > m;
m( 5, 5 ) = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer ended up being

```
return *(Vector<T, N>*)(data+N*row);
```

I don't fully understand the process, I think the explanation was `data+N*row` gives a pointer to the element in the array you want to start from, then you cast that pointer as a Vector type pointer, then dereference so it can be sent and used elsewhere. Maybe someone better suited can explain in the comments.